# Subview not resizing proportionate to super view

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode7

I have a gameView(Just a blue color view with grid lines). I have pinned this gameView to the bottom and the sides of the screen and set the height to 475. When a user taps on this view, I locate the point and create a custom view(fenceView) with the origin and frame of the cell(width and height). In the init method of the fenceView I create a new UIImageView of a fence image and add it as a subview.
[image: Potrait View]

Because of autolayout, when the device is rotated, the width of the gameView changes accordingly. But the problem is, the added fenceViews do not resize. I tried to set the autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight] for both the gameView and the fenceView. But it did not solve the issue.
[image: Landscape mode]

We can see that in the landscape mode, the fence images are not displayed properly. It might be small mistake that I am doing, but I am not able to solve this issue since two days. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using SpriteKit for this?  It seems a better match than using UIViews.

Comment: I am new to swift and IOS. I have no idea about, SpriteKit. I thought it was only for high end game design. I will check it out. I just need to the blue gameView to resize when device rotates(which auto layout does for me) and now I just need to ensure that the subViews resize accordingly. Could you specify if there is any advantage of using SpriteKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.FlexibleHeight` does not need to be used since the overall height will always be 475. Try setting the `autoresizingMask` = [`.FlexibleWidth`, `.FlexibleLeftMargin`, `.FlexibleRightMargin`].

The width will need to change as well as its X position for the larger/smaller width. Both flexible Left and Right margin will apply the increased width to both sides.

Comment: Hi Antonioni, thank you so much for your response. I was almost about to give up and disable auto-layout. The solution worked and the images are resizing properly. Is there any place where I can learn this autosizingMask and stuff like that in more detail? Also is this the right approach to subViews added in code?

Comment: That's a good question. I can't seem to find the documentation on Auto Resizing as I don't think it's used as often anymore. I'd search for auto resizing. It's a very simple means to constrain a view if you know how to use it. Otherwise I stick to AutoLayout Constraints in xib files. Your approach seems like a good easy way to constrain each subview.

Comment: Hi, you said the other approach is to use AutoLayout Constraints. How would I use that on the subViews in this application? For example, if I said, for the fenceView, the leading margin = gameView.leading + 40, then upon, resizing of the gameView, ithe constraint would still be the same and it create errors like in the earlier image right?

Comment: Right, it would keep the same size and hold its left margin. I'm not savvy with adding autolayout constraints programmatically. In interface builder will be the easiest way to use those constraints, but I'm not sure how to obtain the ones you need in such an easier way as auto resizing.